# Sum including $0^0$

Tags: limits, discrete-mathematics, summation, definition

So if I have the sum

$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^n r^k$$

It makes intuitive sense that for $k=0$ the sum equals $n+1$ but of course in this particular situation the sum includes the term $0^0$ which of course is undefined and here we can't take any limits to find what term we should use as this is a discrete sum.

So the question is, is this sum equal to $n+1$ and if so why?

Comment: In order to make these kinds of sums work at $0$ people often use the convention that $0^0 = 1$ (but in general this cannot be true in the sense of limits).

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2267874/589 and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1563452/589

Comment: What is the context of the problem?  So $0^k=0$ for all $k \ne 0$ I'd say $\sum\limits_{r=0}^nr^k=\sum\limits_{r=1}^nr^k$ and for the intuitive sense if $k= 0$ the sum is $n$.  But technically for $k=0$ the sum isn't defined.  I'd default to $0^0 = 0$ before $0^0 =1$ as it "feels" that $0^0= 0^k; k =0$ and $0^k$ defaults to zero.  Ther $r^k$ defaulting to $0^k$ to $0$ seems more fundamental than $r^k$ defaulting to $r^0$ to $1$ does, to me.

Comment: Considering that the term $r=0$ does not contribute to the sum in anyway for positive $k$, and it is not defined for negative $k$,why put it in the sum?

Comment: Are you sure you meant $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n r^k$?  You didn't mean $\sum\limits_{k=0}r^k$.

Comment: @flea I'm sure I meant a sum to n. If it would help I came across this from the second question of the 2008 STEP III paper where it is seems to be expected that I find the sum gives $n+1$.

Comment: The $n$ is not the question.  Are you sure that you mean $\sum_{r=0}^n r^k = 0^k + 1^k + .... + n^k$ and not $\sum_{k=0}^n r^k = r^0 + r^1 + ... +r^n$.  As people point out, the latter is the power series and a power series with $r = 0$  is $1$.  But what you *wrote* appears to seem $r = 0$ is irrelevent.

Comment: Okay, that paper distinctly says $k > 0$.  It's hard from the formula derived if the implication if it were to be expanded to $k=0$ if the sum should be $n$ or $n+1$.  At least not to me.

Comment: @flea Part of the solution involves binomially expanding $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n (r+1)^k$ where the surely last term would be $S_0(n)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to consider the function $f(k) = \sum_{r=0}^{n} r^k$ and the domain of $k$. Assuming $k \in \mathbb{R}$, then we take the right limit $k \to 0^+$ and the left limit $k \to 0^-$.

The left limit does not exist, because we cannot define what it means to have (e.g.) $0^{-0.1}$.

The right limit converges to $n$, because we have (e.g.) $0^{0.1} = 0$.

So you may use the right limit to define $\sum_{r=0}^{n} r^0 = n$. Though you have to mention that you got it through the limit.

---

P.S: Considering that the term $r=0$ does not contribute to the sum in anyway for positive k, and it is not defined for negative k,why put it in the sum?

Comment: but why is this more valid than taking $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} x^0$ where $0^0=1$?

Comment: @andrew because the OP's post can be reduced to where $k$ is the variable. We can fix some arbitrary $n$, say $n=5$. Then we simply have to find out what is the value of the function $f(k) = 0^k + 1^k + 2^k + 3^k + 4^k + 5^k$, when $k=0$. Not the other way around. (OP intuitively thinks it should be $6$.)

Comment: @andrew oops. didn't realise you're the OP 

Comment: Aha yeah, thanks for the comment, deciding which of the two it should be seems very confusing and I'm still not sure why it should be either or and I need a while to figure this out but this seems like the best answer so far.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the exponentiation operation in situations like this should *not* be interpreted as the usual operation on real numbers.

There are a couple of interpretations of what is *really* meant here by the notation $r^k$, but they generally have the property that substituting $k \mapsto 0$ results in the constant $1$. So, further substituting $r \mapsto 0$ still produces the value $1$.

Comment: So you're implying that the exponential function is a different function when taking summations?

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to your saying, one can consider

$$\lim_{k\to0}\sum_{r=0}^n r^k=\sum_{r=0}^n\lim_{k\to0} r^k=n$$

because $\forall k>0:0^k=0$.

Comment: Taking a limit on $r\to0$ makes no sense as $r$ is a discrete dummy variable.